# The constructor DataBaseHelper is undefined

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a DataBaseHelper class setupin my application.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "myDBName";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   



/**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }



}
```

But when I create an instance of this class in my main activity  just to retrieve the data I get the following error. 
( Inside the main activity )

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;






        public class daskj extends Activity {


    ...
    ....
    ....
    ...
    ...


            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error();
            }
            try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
            }



        }
        }
```

Help me out!

```
 [ ... represents lines of code I dint include. ]
```

Comment: You haven't supplied argument `context`

Comment: AFter supplying that, I get an error :if I use this : DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
 
I get one new error which says : Syntax error on token ";" { expected after this token. Syntax error on token ";" { expected after this token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the Context object in your constructor.

You just use: `DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);` if it's issued inside an Activity class

Comment: if I use this : DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
 
I get one new error which says : Syntax error on token ";" { expected after this token.

Comment: You're missing some { probably. Or there is a syntax error. Could you please paste your new code? You just need to add "this" or "getApplicationContext()" inside the new DataBaseHelper() brackets

Comment: Do you put this code inside the onCreate method? If so it's right. If it says that it's a syntax error I think you're writing the code outside the method. Check that there is not a close bracket before your DatabaseHelper creation.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor takes a Context instance as an argument:

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
```

When you're calling

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
```

it is looking for a no-argument constructor.

Comment: Solved. Was a Syntax Error. How can I read Contents of the database in my main activity ?